# jQuery : Calling a recursive function in AJAX succes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, recursion

I have a problem :

```
function getArbre (recherche, div){
    $.ajax({
        //async : false,
        type    : "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        timeout : 2000,
        url     : "test.php?recherche=" + recherche,
        success : function(donnees) {
            if (donnees.Error) {
                alert("Erreur");
            } else {
                console.log(donnees);                                       
                myjson = donnees;
            }           
        },
        complete : function(donnees) {
            console.log("completed");
            //JSONToTree(myjson);
        },
        error: function(donnees, status, err) { 
            console.log(status + " : " + err); 
        }
    }).then(function(data){
        JSONToTree(myjson);
    });
```

And there is my function :

```
function JSONToTree(json){  
    console.log(json.id);       
    for (i = 0; i < json.Children.length; i++) {        
        JSONToTree(json.Children[i].id);            
    }
}
```

I have a problem, I can't read the content of my JSON, can someone help me ?

Comment: What do you mean, you can't get the contents of the json? Is it not being downloaded at all, or is your JSONToTree function failing somehow?  Or is the .then function never being called?

Comment: Is there no error in the `console` like an _Illegal Token_ or something ? I think you are missing your closing bracket at the end of your function`getArbre` or have you just forgotten to include it here?

Comment: her is an example of the json : 
var myjson = '{"id":"1","Children":[{"id":"3","Children":[]},{"id":"4","Children":[]},{"id":"5","Children":[]}]}'
result of the function : 
Object {id: "1", Children: Array[3]} // when i put : console.log(json)
 1
 undefined
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: You could use done() instead of then() (as of JQuery 1.8) and also declare the variable myjson globally.

Comment: can you console the json and check what are you getting? Use console.log(json)

Answer (score -1):

I think you are getting a JSON string and need to parse it. You can do this

```
function JSONToTree(json){
   var jsonObj = JSON.parse(json);  
   console.log(jsonObj.id);       
   for (i = 0; i < jsonObj.Children.length; i++) {        
      JSONToTree(jsonObj.Children[i].id);            
   }
}
```

Comment: This is just a check. If this is the issue with your code, then you need to parse the JSON in the complete function and then pass it to the recursive function.

Comment: The code says `dataType: "json",` so jQuery will parse it even if the server fails to say it is JSON.